# Update-Database fails on foreign key conflict

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I've an application which uses Entity Framework. It contains several migration files which do various database operations. Another user has been making updates directly to the database and now I can't get one of my migrations to apply when I run `Update-Database`. This is the error I get:

> PM> Update-Database
> Build started...
> Build succeeded.
> Failed executing DbCommand (56ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> ALTER TABLE [Balance1Part] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Balance1Part_Balance1_Balance1Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Balance1Id]) REFERENCES [Balance1] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Failed executing DbCommand (56ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> ALTER TABLE [Balance1Part] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Balance1Part_Balance1_Balance1Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Balance1Id]) REFERENCES [Balance1] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE;
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Balance1Part_Balance1_Balance1Id". The conflict occurred in database "db-vrhit05042021", table "dbo.Balance1", column 'Id'.
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> ClientConnectionId:b538f2ff-0a95-4975-ab15-ed75eca72382
> Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Balance1Part_Balance1_Balance1Id". The conflict occurred in database "db-vrhit05042021", table "dbo.Balance1", column 'Id'.

The migration I'm looking to apply here should add the foreign key `FK_Balance1Part_Balance1_Balance1Id` and that foreign key doesn't seem to exist on the database. How can I resolve this issue?

I'm trying to do this on an Azure SQL Server instance.

Here's the migration:

```
public partial class AddIdcolumns : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "CalibrationId",
            table: "Symptoms",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0);

        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "Balance1",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: 0)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");

        migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_Balance1",
            table: "Balance1",
            column: "Id");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Symptoms_CalibrationId",
            table: "Symptoms",
            column: "CalibrationId");

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Balance1Part_Balance1Id",
            table: "Balance1Part",
            column: "Balance1Id");

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Balance1Part_Balance1_Balance1Id",
            table: "Balance1Part",
            column: "Balance1Id",
            principalTable: "Balance1",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);

        migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Symptoms_Calibration_CalibrationId",
            table: "Symptoms",
            column: "CalibrationId",
            principalTable: "Calibration",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Balance1Part_Balance1_Balance1Id",
            table: "Balance1Part");

        migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Symptoms_Calibration_CalibrationId",
            table: "Symptoms");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Symptoms_CalibrationId",
            table: "Symptoms");

        migrationBuilder.DropIndex(
            name: "IX_Balance1Part_Balance1Id",
            table: "Balance1Part");

        migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey(
            name: "PK_Balance1",
            table: "Balance1");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "CalibrationId",
            table: "Symptoms");

        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "Id",
            table: "Balance1");
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class VRHitContext : DbContext
{
    public VRHitContext(DbContextOptions<VRHitContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Organisation> Organisations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientDeviceRegistration> ClientDeviceRegistrations { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DataFile> DataFiles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Symptoms> Symptoms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Balance1> Balance1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Balance1Raw> Balance1Raw { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Balance2> Balance2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Balance2Raw> Balance2Raw { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Calibration> Calibration { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CogMotor1> CogMotor1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CogMotor1Raw> CogMotor1Raw { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CogMotor2> CogMotor2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CogMotor2Raw> CogMotor2Raw { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CogMotor3> CogMotor3 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CogMotor3Raw> CogMotor3Raw { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Gait> Gait { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GaitRaw> GaitRaw { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Interception1> Interception1 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Interception2> Interception2 { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InterceptionPlayerRaw> InterceptionPlayerRaw { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManualDexterity> ManualDexterity { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManualDexterityRaw> ManualDexterityRaw { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => u.UserIdentifier).IsUnique();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Balance1Part>()
            .HasKey(o => new { o.Id, o.Balance1Id });

        // Set default decimal precision.
        foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(decimal) || p.ClrType == typeof(decimal?)))
                    {
                        property.SetColumnType("decimal(38, 10)");
                    }


        // Set default for GUID primary keys.
        foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
            .Where(p => (p.ClrType == typeof(Guid) || p.ClrType == typeof(Guid?)) && p.IsPrimaryKey()))
        {
            property.SetDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What database are you using. Also please add your setup context code and generated migration.

Comment: Sorry. I added them to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this error occurred because you tried to add a foreign key from `Balance1Part.Balance1Id` to `Balance1.Id` but some values in `Balance1Part.Balance1Id` don't match any in `Balance1.Id`. It should be impossible to create a relation that violates referential integrity.  Try checking for missing keys in `Balance1Part`:

```sql
SELECT Balance1Id FROM Balance1Part
WHERE Balance1Id NOT IN
(SELECT Id from Balance1)
```

To resolve add `migrationBuilder.Sql("DELETE FROM [Balance1Part]", true);` to the migration.